# Explain expression: Object followed by Array

Tags: javascript, expression

I saw a javascript expression like this:

```js
var foo = {...}[...];
```

can anyone explain what that means?

Best Regards

#### Update:

this is a code example:

```js
var ENV_PRODUCTION = {
  production: true,
  development: false
}[process.ENV.NODE_ENV|| 'development'];
```

Comment: Please provide a working example, empty object and empty array (`var a = {}[]`) gives syntax error, so it's not valid.

Comment: Was it actually an array (as in `[1,2,3]`), or just something that would evaluate to a property name?  You've simplified the expression too much.

Comment: `var values = {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }; var key = 'key1'; var foo = values[key];`?

Comment: Can you share the exact code?

Comment: `x = { foo: 42, bar: 'baz' }['foo']` is an immediately invoked object literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will return the inner value by key value [see](https://jsbin.com/pocaveyati/edit?html,js,console,output):

```
var foo = {
 "1": "Jam",
"2":"Stuff"}[1];

var bar = {
 "1": "Jam",
"2":"Stuff"}[2];
```

```js
var foo = {
 "1": "Jam",
"2":"Stuff"}[1];

var bar = {
 "1": "Jam",
"2":"Stuff"}[2];

var jam = {
 "1": "Jam",
"B":"Other Stuff"}['B'];

var foobar = {
 "...": "...",
"B":"Other Stuff"}['...'];

console.log(foo, bar, jam, foobar)
```

[Further documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

Its a reference to element of the object.

Try in console:

```
var x = {a:1}['a'];
```

x = 1

Answer (score 0):

This is a [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator as per ES6

> The spread syntax allows an expression to be expanded in places where
>   multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for
>   array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment)
>   are expected.

Comment: I suspect the `...` in this case is just a simplification by the OP and is meant to represent other stuff, rather than be the spread operator.

Comment: @JamesThorpe oh..ok. I guess then OP should show the exact code.

Comment: I think isn't destructuring, probably @Newton answer is correct. Could you provide an example of your assertion?

Comment: @Hitmands sorry, not sure if I can give a relevant answer unless you share the exact code that you saw.